# Order In which to generate Rails application features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, scaffold

I'm new to Rails and programming in general. I'm a bit confused and wondering about common practices when building a rails application from scratch.

Is there a proper order of how and when things should be generated? Obviously `rails generate new` should be the first, but should Devise or any other authentication system be the next in line, or should `rails generate scaffold ****` be done before, etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the app, then run any rails engines such as devise, then scaffold (in your example). Also remember to run migrations as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Rails application building is done when **rails generate new** is executed. After that you can generate all what you need in any order. It doesn't make sence to talk about any common practices in this case.